# Difference between Receipt & Confirmation callbacks

Tags: web3js, sendsignedtransaction

I'd like to verify programmatically that a transaction was successful - that is the Etherum network itself recognizes that for a given transaction hash, it was valid.

Using web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction returned promise, there's two events - one 'confirmation', the other 'receipt'.

Can I rely on the 'receipt' callback to ascertain that a transaction truly occurred? Or do I have to rely on the 'confirmation' call back as well? If so - how?

Similarly, reading [getTransactionReceipt](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt) it mentions that -

> The receipt is not available for pending transactions and returns null.

So, if I do get a receipt then - it means the transaction is no longer 'pending' ? That is, was successful?

Comment: Check this https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/consensus-mechanisms/pow/#finality

Comment: So I should wait until I get 6 confirmation callbacks?

Comment: 3 is enough but more is better

Comment: Let's assume the server crashes while the confirmations are being sent. After the server goes back online, how do I measure the transaction was validated?

Comment: When u send a tx you get its hash directly even if it is pending und not confirmed, u need to store that transaction hash and then use it to check if it valid and included in a block

Comment: Got it - save the tx hash. But which web3 API enables me to do check it's in a block?

Comment: the same method getTransactionReceipt